# Switching the Derivative From One Function to the Other Inside an Integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be open and bounded by $\partial \Omega$ sufficiently smooth. Let $u \in C^k(\bar{\Omega})$ and $\phi \in C_0^\infty (\Omega)$ for a positive integer k. Show that:
$$
\int_\Omega uD^{\alpha}\phi dx = (-1)^{|a|}\int_{\Omega}\phi D^\alpha udx
$$
for any multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| <k$.

To me, this problem looks like an application of one of the fundamental theorems of calculus (stoke's, divergence, etc.). However, I might be wrong. I tried to work out the LHS but couldn't get to the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

It's integration by parts, if you assume that all derivatives of $\phi$ go to zero at the boundary.